# How can use a azure table class object's column names manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-table-storage

I want to use a model class which represents a table storage table, in a loop assign values to this class object. I want to assign like the following Datatable example.

```
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();

dtable.Columns.Add("item1", typeof(string));
dtable.Columns.Add("item2", typeof(string));
dtable.Columns.Add("item3", typeof(string));
var row = dtable.NewRow();
row["item1"] = "example1";
row["item2"] = "example2";
row["item3"] = "example3";
```

Here I can assign values to Datatable row as row["item1"];

In case of Table storage table value is assigning like following way ,

```
var tableRow = new ExampleTableEntity();
tableRow.PartitionKey = "20180618";
tabeleRow.RowKey = DateTime.Now;
```

How can I represent `tableRow.PartitionKey` to like `tableRow["PartitionKey"]`?
Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [TableEntity.Flatten Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.flatten?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableEntity_Flatten_System_Object_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) flattens entity and returns a `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` containing all properties of the specified entity. This will allow you to access the properties using the index operator.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any working example? I didn't get any example code.

Comment: Just try `TableEntity.Flatten(tableRow, new OperationContext())["PartitionKey"]`